# How can I set a shadow on a UILabel it's backgroundframe?

Tags: iphone, background, uilabel, layer, shadow

I've got a UILabel and this label has got a filled backgroundcolor (It's a header for my textView). I want to enable a shadow so that this dark shadow falls over the textview.

I'm already at the point where I've implemented a shadow on the text of my label.

```
        descriptionLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        descriptionLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(4.0f, 0.0f);
        descriptionLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
        descriptionLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
```

However I want to have the shadow below the complete frame of the label (so not the text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the shadow path to be an explicit rectangle rather than using the layer contents:

```
CGPathRef shadowPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(descriptionLabel.bounds, NULL);
descriptionLabel.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
CGPathRelease(shadowPath);
```

This is also a pretty common technique to improve the rendering performance when adding shadows to a view. A fixed rectangle shadow will be many times faster to draw than one based off the layer contents.